External HDD has a lost partition with my data but I cannot access on my Laptop
Is there a way to recover Lost Partition from an External Harddisk? On my windows laptop my external harddisk was connected and accidently my HDD got chosen as the Boot Disk image and a FAT32 partition got created over my existing data. So not I cannot access my personal data but I can see the files of the Boot Image Disk. I used some Partition Recovery software through which I can see my unused partition as "Lost Partition" but to recover that I need to purchase the software which costs a lot.
Is there any solution to this or any better software to recover. I have a Mac Book too which I can use.

This question is similar to: Recover a partition. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also, if the data is of sufficient value to be worth commercial data recovery, get an estimate of cost and chances of success.
